Error 302 after Configuration alert msteam in watcher elasticsearch
Last week I have complete configure alert Microsoft Teams integration to watcher

send_to_teams": {
"webhook": {
"scheme": "https",
"host": "xxx.webhook.office.com",
"port": 443,
"method": "post",
"path": "/",
"params": {},
"headers": {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
},
"body": """{"APM Failed Transaction Rate Alert HTTP 500" : { "Found {{ctx.payload.hits.total}}" : { "HTTP errors in the last minute {{alert.actionGroup}}{{^context.isRatio}}{{#context.group}}{{context.group}} - {{/context.group}}{{context.matchingDocuments}} log entries have matched the following conditions: {{context.conditions}}{{/context.isRatio}}{{#context.isRatio}}{{#context.group}}{{context.group}} - {{/context.group}} Ratio of the count of log entries matching {{context.numeratorConditions}} to the count of log entries matching {{context.denominatorConditions}} was {{context.ratio}}{{/context.isRatio}}" : "Service Name: {{ctx.payload.hits.hits.0._source.service.name}}"}}}"""
}

But I don't understand why it doesn't display the alert on ms team even though the email still displays the alert normally . I checked and see it display error 302. Please help solve this problem. Thank you so much.
enter image description here
